# Apache 2.4 permissions issue

Tags: apache2.4

I have Apache 2.4 installed using Homebrew on my Mac. The following does not work, it allows access to the entire filesystem:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

If I enable `access_compat_module` then change the above block to the block below, it works as expected. I didn't make any other changes to `httpd.conf`.

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

I thought these were equivalent but clearly something is not working. I have `authz_core_module` enabled in both cases. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want only share '/path/to/share'

then you need not to touch

```
 < Directory    / >
```

instead update the

```
 < Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents" >
```

to let it be:

```
< Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents" >

 Options FollowSymLinks Indexes

 MultiviewsMatch Any 

 AllowOverride None 

 Require all granted

 < /Directory >
```

then you can create a soft link under the

```
  /Library/WebServer/Documents
```

to let it point to

```
  /path/to/share
```

and give the

```
  /path

  /path/to

  /path/to/share
```

enough permission to make it possible to access from

```
   http://<your domain name>/
```

this is System level to share some special directory.

there is also other ways to share some special directory in your server

, e.g. Alias or user level

```
   http://<your domain name>/~<username>
```

reference [documents](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html)